# Is it possible to checkout all files in binary mode from CVS?

Tags: cvs

I do have a CVS project called "Merlin". When I checkout entire project on linux all the files are correct. When I checkout the project on Windows there is an extra newline introduced after each line, causing failure script execution in few cases as given below -

Code on linux -

```
if key_name in self and isinstance(self[key_name], dict) and \
    platform_name in self[key_name]:
```

Code on windows -

```
if key_name in self and isinstance(self[key_name], dict) and \

    platform_name in self[key_name]:
```

This has happened with almost 40+ py files and 1000+ errors introduced after cvs checkout on windows..

Comment: I am not crosplatforming the CVS, but if you are using some nice client on Win try to search for some line ending convertion options.

Comment: Tortoise CVS has this option.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Tortoise CVS client provides this option.

[image: TortoiseCVS]